# Understanding on Termination Connector of State Diagram in IBM Rhapsody

Tags: c++, uml, rhapsody

In IBM Rhapsody if i have created instance of a class using new, then Do we have to take care for deallocating memory  by calling delete or Termination Connector will handle its destruction with memory deallocation in its State Diagram??

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ and the OXF (Object Execution Framework), then rather than calling `delete`, you should call `destroy()` on the object you want to delete.

Example:

```
C *c = new C();

// cleanup
c->destroy();
```

Note: Deleting an `OMReactive` object while the OXF is running is not a good idea. The OXF might try to dispatch an event to the object that does not exist anymoremore.