# Find when active class destruction has completed in IBM Rhapsody

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I need to destroy an instance of a class with a statechart in IBM Rhapsody with the OXF framework, and find when the destruction has completed.

From other questions (1) I can see that calling `delete` on the object is a bad idea as any pending events in the event queue will crash the program.

Calling `destroy()` cleans up pending events as part of the destruction but is there a way to find when the destruction has completed?

Note that I have tried enabling the `CPP_CG::Framework::UseDirectReactiveDeletion` option but this does not clean up pending events before deletion so leads to crashes.

Thanks for the help

(1) [Understanding on Termination Connector of State Diagram in IBM Rhapsody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626872/understanding-on-termination-connector-of-state-diagram-in-ibm-rhapsody)

Answer (score 1):

You may overload the destructor of the class, it is called if class is deleted.